# When should removeStickyEvent(...) be called?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, event-bus

I'm using the GreenRobot EventBus lib on Android.

Could someone tell me, what's best practice for calling the removeStickyEvent(...)? Up-Action, back button pressed, ...?

Thank you guys.

Comment: That would depend entirely upon what you are using the sticky event for.

Comment: That makes sense. I asked that question because I'm afraid of creating sticky events which are maybe not consumed and stay unnecessary in memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question about the Event object staying in memory: only the last sticky event posted stays in memory for each given type.

Take a look at the source [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/EventBus/src/org/greenrobot/eventbus/EventBus.java).

Basically to summarize: Eventbus keeps a map of stickyEvents with the key being class type and the value being the field. So when a new sticky event is posted with `EventBus.postSticky(event)` the event posted overwrites the old event. So I think you are safe from building up many sticky events.

I was worried about that also. I wish it was explained better in the docs but at least its open source so we can look inside and see whats happening.

I guess to answer your question more completely. When should you remove a sticky event? When you don't want calls to get the sticky event to not return anything. When exactly that is is an application specific requirement. Good luck.